Passing a dict to the vars variable in a task in ansible errors
I have the following ansible code:
```
- name: Install and configure PGS servers for RZ
  hosts: pgs_rzdb_servers
  tasks:
    - name: Prepare pgs_server role variables
      set_fact:
        pgs_server_custom_role_vars: >-
          {{
            {
              'pgs_server_version': pgs_rzdb_server_version,
              'pgs_server_port': pgs_rzdb_server_port,
              'pgs_server_pg_hba_rules': pgs_rzdb_server_pg_hba_rules,
              'pgs_server_max_connections': pgs_rzdb_server_max_connections,
              'pgs_server_idle_in_transaction_session_timeout': pgs_rzdb_server_idle_in_transaction_session_timeout,
              'pgs_server_marker': 'RZDB'
            }
            | dict2items
            | selectattr('value', 'defined')
            | items2dict
          }}

    - debug:
        msg: "Role variables: {{ pgs_server_custom_role_vars }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "Role variables: {{ pgs_server_custom_role_vars | type_debug }}"

    - name: pgs_server
      import_role:
        name: pgs_server
      vars: "{{ pgs_server_custom_role_vars }}"
      tags:
        - pgs_server

Even though I get the following debug messages when I comment out vars:
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** ok: [lspostgres02.ls.local] => { "msg": "Role variables: {'ls_pgs_server_version': 13, 'ls_pgs_server_port': 5431, 'ls_pgs_server_pg_hba_rules': [{'contype': 'host', 'users': 'all', 'source': 'lxserver.ls.local', 'databases': 'all', 'method': 'md5'}, {'contype': 'host', 'users': 'all', 'source': '192.168.69.0/24', 'databases': 'all', 'method': 'md5'}], 'ls_pgs_server_marker': 'RZDB'}" }

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** ok: [lspostgres02.ls.local] => { "msg": "Role variables: dict" }

when I uncomment this line I get the following error:
ERROR! Vars in a IncludeRole must be specified as a dictionary

The error appears to be in '/mnt/c/Users/dhe/Documents/Checkouts/ls-ansible/ls_pgs_rzdb_servers.yml': line 30, column 13, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

        name: pgs_server
      vars: "{{ pgs_server_custom_role_vars }}"
            ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"

Is this a bug, or what am I doing wrong here?
I'm using ansible [core 2.16.6]
I expect this to just work correctly, because the documentation of ansible tells me, that I have to pass
Dictionary/map of variables here.

It might be possible in the following way and would work for dynamically generated var files too, but I consider such as bad practice.

You can't pass dictionary into 'vars'. There is specific reason for that (outside of the fact, that Jinja is not interpolated for 'var' stanza).
Every key in the yaml dictionaries in ansible is so-called 'unsafe' text, that means, you can't put Jinja there, no matter how hard you try.
This won't work too:
vars:
  "{{ key_name }}": "{{ key_value }}"

for the same reason.
The thing you are trying to do is not very 'ansible-way', but if you insist, you can write them into a file on the controller and then load as 'include_vars' stanza.

Hey, thanks for the clarification! Actually, I would like to do this since we might have 2 different ls_pgs_server role installations on the same server but with different port, settings, etc. So I could still use the same role, but different settings while just "overwriting" them in the playbook. Is there maybe a better way to implement this I don't know of yet?

Use role parameters and fill them in the play. Don't pass whole dictionaries, it make things hard to read and to debug.
